# Excel - combining of function MATCH for multiple conditions

Tags: excel, match, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions, vba

I have column M, which contains text. I would like to create a checker (cell M1), which would check if columns M3:M999999 contains words "Credit note" or "Internal credit note" or "Invoice correction", if so, I would like to be notified with some message, which has been shown in the cell M1.

I've tried this combination:

```
=IF(OR(M3:M999999="Invoice correction",M3:M999999="Internal credit note",M3:M999999="Credit note"), "NEEDS TO CHECK!", "OK")
```

But it shows me error #VALUE, since it has problem the range, it works fine for 1 cell.

I tried to use it with function `=MATCH` but it can be used also for 1 cell only.

Do you know, how to use these or other function for multiple conditions, please? Or if the VBA would be better solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This seems to be an array formula so commit it by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.

Comment: Wow, many thanks! Havent found about it. It works as I expected for the syntax, what I' ve posted in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the *IF* formula expects a check on one single cell, not an array. You will need to change the formula to make the checks in all the column with *COUNTIF*:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF(M3:M999999, "Invoice correction") > 0, COUNTIF(M3:M999999, "Internal credit note") > 0, COUNTIF(M3:M999999, "Credit note") > 0), "NEEDS TO CHECK!", "OK")
```

Comment: I see, thank you! It works as well as the solution from @Mrig